# Out of Memory exception while loading image to BitMap

Tags: c#, bitmap, out-of-memory, fromfile

I am working on app, that will edit images. But it crashes because of `system.outofmemoryexception`, when I try to load the image from disc. My RAM is pretty empty, but what I observed is, that app crashes, when the memory reach 30MB in memory. So maybe I need to allocate more memory? Here is the code, where the exception is called:

`using(Bitmap DocasnyObrazek = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(otevreniSouboru.FileName)) {...}`
Here is full code for opening an loading image:

```
namespace Editor_Obrázků_2._0
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Bitmap Obrazek;//datová složka pro obrázek
        Color[,] Barvy; //datová složka pro barvy
        private void OtevriSoubor() //otevření souboru
        {
            OpenFileDialog otevreniSouboru = new OpenFileDialog();//deklarace metody
            otevreniSouboru.Filter = "Obrázky (*.bmp, *.jpg|*.bmp; *.jpg";//povolené přípony souboru
            otevreniSouboru.ShowDialog();//zobrazí okno pro vybrání souboru
            if (otevreniSouboru.FileName != "") //jestli existuje soubor tak otevřít
            {
                using(Bitmap DocasnyObrazek = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(otevreniSouboru.FileName))//using se stará o pamět, Obrázek bude přetypován na Bitmap
                {
                    if (DocasnyObrazek.Width <= 500 && DocasnyObrazek.Height <= 500) //pokud je menší než 500x500
                    {
                        if (Obrazek != null)
                        {
                            Obrazek.Dispose();
                            Obrazek = null;
                        }
                        Obrazek = (Bitmap)DocasnyObrazek.Clone();//přetypování a nahrání dat    "clone" neodkazuje na data ale předává je
                        Barvy = new Color[Obrazek.Width, Obrazek.Height]; //pole pro barvy
                        for (int sloupec = 0; sloupec < Obrazek.Width; sloupec++)//nahrání barev
                            for (int radek = 0; radek < Obrazek.Height; radek++)
                            {
                                Barvy[sloupec, radek] = Obrazek.GetPixel(sloupec, radek);
                            }
                        this.seznamEfektů.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    else//obrázek je příliš velký nelze načíst
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Obrázek je příliš velký", "Chyba", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OtevriSoubor();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Obrazek != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Obrazek, 10, 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How large is the image and what pixelformat does it have?

Answer (score 1):

I found out, why this wasn't working. In the documentation the `outofmemoryexception` refers to problem with the jpg or bmp file, not problem with memory.